# How to you turn on a site and connect two sites when there are multiple dimensions?

Tags: algorithm, union-find

Normally when I use union find, I create a one-dimensional array and initialize the value at each index with its position in the array. So for a 5 element array each element will have the same value as their index (`0-4`).

If I use union find data structure that has multiple dimensions, it becomes more difficult. Say I have a grid of 10x10 sites, each site is turned off initially (a mutli-dimensional array, each index having value `-1`). My implementation provides a method for turning the site on, where you specify the dimension of the array. `open(4, 3)` will go to the 4th row and turn on the 3rd site on the grid. If I were to turn this site on, what value will I give the index, and how?

I was thinking I give it the unique value of its position relative to the first site. So the site at position `(4, 3)` will be given the value 43 (4 rows of 10 sites down + three sites to the right). But this requires going through each site and counting each element to get the value that will be stored, which is `O(n)`. I could convert `4` and `3` to strings and combine them, but this is an exercise from a lecture and I don't think that's what they want us to do.

Moreover, I encounter the same problem when connecting two sites on the grid. How can I determine what value to represent the connection without going through most of the array to find their indices?

Is there a better way to do what I'm attempting?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. There are three operations you need to implement: `new`, `union`, and `find`. Using an array (as you suggest) means that `new` is O(1), `union` is O(n), and `find` is O(1).  Given a two-dimensional array with 10 columns, it's perfectly valid to implement `new` by assigning the value `y*10+x` to the location `array[y][x]`. If you want to support larger arrays, you could assign a value of (y*1000+x). That would allow you to support arrays of up to 1000x1000.

Comment: @user3386109 Yes that's what I wanted. And what operation did you mean by `new`? I haven't heard of that one.

Comment: I think that what I call `new` is what you are calling `open`. It's the operation that creates a new set that has one element.

Comment: @user3386109 My exercise tells me to see if there is a path connecting a given site to the top row of the grid. The lecturer said to create a "virtual site" at the top which connects to all of the sites on the top. Then I can check if a given site connects to the top row - by checking the top site. But how exactly can I create this top site?

Comment: The meaning of the word `path` is not clear. What is a `path` and how is a `path` formed?

Comment: @user3386109 When there are open sites on the grid that connect to each other. There's a path from A to B if there are open sites that connect A and B together.

Comment: Ok, so basically if you `open(4,3)`, you have a set with one element at point {4,3}. You then need to check above, below, left and right from that point, and `union` with the sets at those locations, if any. (This may result in as many as 4 `union` operations). If the resulting union includes the top row, then you have a path to the top row. Note that you should start by calling `open` on every element in the top row, and then create the union of all of the sets in the top row.

Comment: @user3386109 So at most I will be making 4 `union` calls? What if I want to see if a site at the very bottom of a 20x20 grid has a path to the top? Won't that take more than 4 union calls to get to the top?

Comment: Actually you'll be making as many as 4 `union` calls every time you `open` a new site. So by the time you get around to `open` a site on row 20, you will already have a `set` that connects from row 19 all the way to row 0. Now, of course, you could open the sites out of order, so initially the site on row 20 isn't in the `set` that connects to row 0. But as you `open` more sites, eventually the site on row 20 will `union` into a set that connects to row 0. The point is that it could take hundreds of `union` calls to connect row 20 to row 0. But it takes at most 4 union calls for each `open`.